# Ubuntu Software application not responding in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-center, responsiveness

The Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 20.04 is useless right now. Whenever I try to select or search for a package, it renders an infinite spinning loader and that's it. Anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Comment: Which version and flavor of Ubuntu?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi **OS:** Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64. **Kernel:** 5.11.0-27-generic.

Comment: Try the following commands in a terminal, and restart the computer, and check if the issue still persists. `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` and `sudo snap refresh`.